# How to add a project as a dependency on a GWT/GAE project

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt, plugins

I have created a "google project"... went new web project with the gwt/gae plugin.  Now I want to reference code in another project.

- I had the project to the build path and start the project. GAE does not find the classes in the dependenct project.
- I tried then adding the dynamic web module facet to the google project and then editing the deployment assembly and adding the project like that... didn't work.

The way I run the project is "run as web application".

How do I add a project as a dependency onto a google project? I am using Helios Eclipse, latest google plugin, gwt and gae.

**UPDATE:**

This is not actually a "gwt" project - does not have a front end. It is a back end GAE project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For deployment, you can't currently (as of Gwt 2.2) deploy a gwt project that references other gwt projects directly.  Instead, you have to export the other projects to jar files and include the jar files on the build path of the head project. So long as those jar files are present in the war/WEB-INF/lib then it will deploy correctly.

For testing purposes, you can reference the projects themselves on the build path for hosted mode, but as soon as you deploy it, you need to use the exported jar in the lib directory.

Answer (score 1):

If your other project is also a gwt project and you want to use classes from the *.client package, you need to "inherit" the module in your other project. See http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideModules . If that's not the problem, maybe you could explain a little more what you mean by "does not find the classes". Are the classes not found at compile time? Runtime? What is the actual message?

Comment: I get a ClassNotFoundException on startup - the class it is looking for is in the "other" project.